# Are PreparedStatements cached by CQL string? Does Datastax PreparedStatement retain statement ID?

Tags: cassandra, prepared-statement, cassandra-2.0

Are the statement caches on server and client side cached strictly by the string rendition of the PreparedStatement, or something else?  In other words, if two different PreparedStatements are created by different means, but end up having exactly the same CQL textual rendering, will they both have to be prepared (assuming the same server)?  If they come from different clients?

Much less importantly... under what conditions will a client be able to translate from PreparedStatement to statement ID, without consulting the server?

(I'm coming from Oracle experience, if that helps.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if two different PreparedStatements are created by different means,
>   but end up having exactly the same CQL textual rendering, will they
>   both have to be prepared (assuming the same server)? If they come from
>   different clients?

**Executing same statement from different clients**
Just ran a test on this, two clients execute an identical prepared statement twice, the cql statement cache in `o.a.c.cql3.QueryProcessor#preparedStatements` ended up storing 2 statements even though their string rendition was identical meaning PreparedStatements by different clients are cached.

**Executing same statement from same client**
Duplicate statements from a single client are not cached twice, so they can be reused and don't have to be re-compiled, when the client executes the same prepared statement it only sends over the statement id and the parameters.